# What category would a new rulemaking procedural patent for the Federal Register be classified?

Tags: government-rights

The United States has a very stringent paper chase for its Federal Register which may be maintained using computer applications. The question: Which category of patents would a new rulemaking procedural for the Federal Register be classified?

Comment: Do you mean which chapter of the Code of Federal Regulations covers patent topics?

Comment: I would assume the most appropriate channel. Patent filings are regulated by the CFR. Rulemaking is a CFR administrative procedural. Yet, a technology patent may be filed using standing CFR procedural with respect of both administrations without invoking CFR regulations by means of categorizing its classification (i.e.: construction, information technology, etc). Under the auspiciousness of fairness to standing administration, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question and the comment from the OP but, once made, patent rules go in chapter 37 of the CFR. The Federal Register is published daily and any proposed USPTO rule making would go into the next daily issue.

Comment: @Habatchii  If you think this answer is great, you should accept it by clicking in the check mark.